# Visual Studio 2022 push to custom docker container stopped working after changing image name

Tags: docker, visual-studio, publish, pubxml

I have a visual studio .pubxml for publish into a custom docker container with a dockerfile.

It's working well, the build generates the image and then the push is done correctly.

The problem is that I need to change the image name to push, by default it takes the project name.

```
<Project>
<PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>Custom</WebPublishMethod>
    <DockerPublish>true</DockerPublish>
    <RegistryUrl>https://myUrl</RegistryUrl>
    <UserName>XXXXX</UserName>
    <PublishImageTag>latest</PublishImageTag>
    <PublishProvider>ContainerRegistry</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <_TargetId>DockerCustomContainerRegistry</_TargetId>
    <!--<DockerfileBuildArguments>-t NEWNAME</DockerfileBuildArguments>-->
    <DockerfileTag>NEWNAME</DockerfileTag>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is my .pubxml, with the DockerfileBuildArguments -t NEWNAME  or with the DockerfileTag NEWNAME. The image that is generated is correct. But when visual studio try to do the push is still searching for the old named image (that is not generated now)

```
docker push PROJECTNAME:latest
```

But I want visual studio to do

```
docker push NEWNAME:latest
```

and I'm getting this error cause the image with the PROJECTNAME is not generated now:

```
Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.Docker.DockerCommandException: Running the docker.exe tag command failed.
Error response from daemon: No such image: PROJECTNAME:latest
```

Any ideas of how I can change that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`<DockerfileTag>NEWNAME</DockerfileTag>` needs to go into the project file not the publish profile.

Comment: Hi, 

I also tried that and it's not working, if you see in the question the DockerfileBuildArguments is commented

Comment: In the question you've commented out `-t NEWNAME` the fix is to do `-t PROJECTNAME`

Comment: yes, cause i need a NEWNAME image, i dont want a PROJECTNAME image

Comment: Egg on my face, I just triple checked and the work-around fixes the build error, but pushed the wrong image. You do need to put the property DockerfileTag into the project file.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

edit Docker Compose

The docker-compose.yml file references the name of the image that's created when the project runs:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  hellodockertools:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}NEWNAME
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: HelloDockerTools/Dockerfile
```

The NEWNAME:latest image is generated when the app runs in Release mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJUR8.png)

the docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.1